# How do I uninstall a new GNOME download?

Tags: gnome, mount, 15.04

How do I access and uninstall new GNOME 15 something from my 4TB back-up? I'm a computer novice. Just downloaded Ubuntu, newest edition, trying to be updated, so tried to download GNOME newest edition 15 something, is big so I put it to my back-up 4TB drive. Now can't access the drive at all.
Please, want to uninstall the new GNOME, get what I need out of my back-up, then try to download something else, or a different GNOME.

The error:

```
 Unable to mount Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 amd64
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/paul/Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 amd64: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/paul/Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 amd64"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, 
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error 
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try 
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: Is your system dual boot?

Comment: Hunter, Ty, no not a dual boot. I start-up my hp Pavilion dv6 with a button then via a USB plug-in the TB drive. I don't think that is dual-boot. You're fast! Very much thanks for that. Paul

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

In the live session, open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Ty kyodake, I did what you said and got this:

Comment: Ooops: paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ fsck -y /dev/.sbd1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/.sbd1
Possibly non-existent device?
paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ fsck-y/dev/sdb1
bash: fsck-y/dev/sdb1: No such file or directory
paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ 
I tried, what did I do wrong?

Comment: sudo  space fsck space  -y space /dev/sdb1

Comment: Ty for your patience. the sudo asks for a password and the back-up does not have a password. I hit the enter and does nothing. Is that the problem?

Comment: `sudo -i` enters a root shell so you can do stuff as the superuser, `fsck` checks the disk (sudo asking for a password shouldn't be the problem, its supposed to do that). Could please you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/633927/edit) into your question the output of `dmesg | tail -50` and `sudo fdisk -l` just after plugging the external harddisk in?

Comment: You are good! Tried again first thing after waking-up. Got this message:    paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for paul: 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing changes.
/dev/sdb1: 139 files, 1260370/1989925 clusters
paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
/dev/sdb1: 139 files, 1260370/1989925 clusters

Comment: OK, did it. 4TB is formated NTFS if that helps. ran your message: paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ dmeg
No command 'dmeg' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dmesg' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'dreg' from package 'emboss' (universe)
dmeg: command not found
paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ tail -50
sudo fdisk -1

Comment: WOW, typed dmsg again got this plus about 15 more pages, removed a small USB will run again. :[    1.318545] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found